# Sql Server Deleting Certain Duplicate records from a temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that returns a stock list and if there is no stock above a certain dimension then it returns 0 stock but if returns stock above the dimension it excludes the entry without stock for that colour,

but I also want to keep records where there is two different locations containing stock I.E in the output the colour "Cinder Slate"

so far I have:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(
    brand   VARCHAR(500), 
    Colour  VARCHAR(500), 
    finish  VARCHAR(50),
    Length  INT, 
    width   INT, 
    QTY     INT, 
    loc     VARCHAR(10) 
)
DECLARE @length INT,
        @width  INT,
        @loc    VARCHAR(10),
        @Qty    INT 

SET @length = 0
SET @width  = 0 
SET @Qty    = 0
SET @loc    = 'None' 

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    tblbrand.brand,
    tblcolour.colour,
    tblfinish.finish, 
    @length,
    @width, 
    @qty,
    @loc
FROM  tblcolour 
INNER JOIN tbloffcut
    ON tblcolour.colourid = tbloffcut.colourid 
INNER JOIN tblfinish 
    ON tblcolour.finishid = tblfinish.finishid 
INNER JOIN tblbrand
    ON tblcolour.brandid = tblbrand.brandid
WHERE
    tbloffcut.length < 3600
    AND tbloffcut.width < 1500
    AND  tblbrand.brand = 'Arborite'

INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT 
    tblbrand.brand,
    tblcolour.colour,
    tblfinish.finish, 
    tbloffcut.length,
    tbloffcut.width,
    tbloffcut.quantity,
    tbloffcut.location
FROM tblbrand
INNER JOIN tblcolour
    ON tblbrand.brandid = tblcolour.brandid 
INNER JOIN tbloffcut 
    ON tblcolour.colourid = tbloffcut.colourid 
INNER JOIN tblfinish
    ON tblbrand.brandid = tblfinish.brandid
    AND tblcolour.finishid = tblfinish.finishid
WHERE
    tblbrand.brand = 'Arborite'
    AND tbloffcut.length >= 3600
    AND tbloffcut.width >= 1500
ORDER BY 
    tblcolour.colour

SELECT * 
FROM @t1 
ORDER BY 
    Colour,
    Length DESC,
    width DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help others understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: the image contains the sample data

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <a href='http://postimage.org/' target='_blank'><img src='http://s2.postimg.org/b4suimo8p/remove_Duplicates.jpg' border='0' alt="remove Duplicates" /></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='http://postimage.org/'>upload gambar</a><br /><br />


<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: I have highlighted the example of fields that need to be removed